# Reference Multiple RegEx in google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am in the process of importing some data where the descriptions are essentially the same, but may have some small variation. I started with adding substitute and regreplace to deal with these. The formula is getting a little long so wanted to know if I could replace the specific substitute and regreplace in the formula bar and rather use a reference to a range which has all the replacements in.

For example

```
Received Text: 
`Apple red
Apple green
Apple yellow`
Output required:
`Apple`
```

if it was the same pattern e,g, apple and then colour, and all I wanted was apple, easy enough, but as I get more data, new patterns emerge that I need to deal with, so each time I need to add to the formula.

The second Example with 2 patterns

```
Received Text
Apple red
Apple green
car-001-aa
bike-001-aa
Output required:
Apple
Car
bike
```

so now I need to deal with removing colour if it starts with apple or if the string contains -001-aa, remove the -001-aa

here is the formula I have at the moment:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(F2:F ="",,if(J2:J&" "&G2:G=$M$2,$N$2,Trim (  REGEXREPLACE (SUBSTITUTE (SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(lower(F2:F)," on [0-9]{2} [a-zA-Z]{3}",),"clp",""),"bcc",""), "monzo-[A-Za-z]{5} ft", " savings pot")))))
```

as you can see I am currently dealing with 4 different patterns so what I wanted to know is if could I replace:

```
(  REGEXREPLACE (SUBSTITUTE (SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(lower(F2:F)," on [0-9]{2} [a-zA-Z]{3}",),"clp",""),"bcc",""), "monzo-[A-Za-z]{5} ft", " savings pot"))
```

with a reference to a range which would contain the patterns and function to use e.g.

```
Cell A1: REGEXREPLACE(" on [0-9]{2} [a-zA-Z]{3}",)
Cell A2: SUBSTITUTE("clp","")
Cell A3: SUBSTITUTE("bcc","")
Cell A4: REDEXREPLACE("monzo-[A-Za-z]{5} ft", " savings pot")
Cell A5: new pattern
```

and so on and so on.

so if I used the Apple example, I would have a separate range which would include all the patterns to test for

e.g.

1. Replace (Apple).*, Apple"
2. Remove string = -001-aa

Later on if I see a new pattern I could just add it to the list of patterns and the formula would include the new pattern

so in my main sheet, I would have a formula that be something like B1 = patterns(A1)

Thanks in advance for any help or pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`REDUCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597?hl=en) function:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(REDUCE(A2:A,D2:D,LAMBDA(a,c,REGEXREPLACE(a,c,OFFSET(c,,1))))))
```

[image]